# sharing failed: invalid field name when we share a file with an external user in share point online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Getting an error as

> "sharing failed: invalid field name"

when we share a file with an external user in share point online.

Comment: Ho ware you entering the external user's info? Is it the first time the external user has been added to anything in SharePoint? If it is the first time, just enter the email of the user

Comment: sharing a document with the external user and i get the error message

Comment: A colleague of mine just had this same issue. In this case we are using Excel online via Office 365 and got this problem sharing it with an external client.